# debugging the build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Building in windows powershell . Already tried `java version 8` and gradle update

./gradlew build.gradle
Support for running Gradle using Java 7 has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please see https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_cross_compilation for more details.

**FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.**

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\ProjectChaayos\KettleAndroid\assembly\build.gradle' line: 10
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':assembly'.

  > java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/build/gradle/AppPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Below is the build.gradle file on which error is shown in console i.e

> assembly/build.gradle

```
         buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/glomadrian/maven"
    }
    maven {

        url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-releases/"
    }

    google()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion project.ext.compileSdkVersion
    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
    }
    /*splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }*/

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kettle.android_phase3"
        minSdkVersion project.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion project.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Assembly screen v2 app"

        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            versionNameSuffix '-DEBUG'
            resValue "string", "app_name", "Assembly screen app v2 debug"
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildToolsVersion project.ext.buildToolsVersion

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':common')
    compile project(':printer')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'testfairy:testfairy-android-sdk:1.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:1.1.0'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.1.3'
}
```

As you can see error thrown on line 10

```
:apply plugin'com.android.application'
```

> gradle-wrapper.properties:-

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle file and gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: @Dean Marcussen posted required files

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're referencing gradle in the build.gradle file

I would expect to see the dependency listed like

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

with the appropriate gradle version

Comment: its already refrencing from master gradle file. n btw this issue is resolved after setting java home from terminal.